# Showing range name next to the range

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013, named-ranges

In Excel 2013, I'm using named ranges on a sheet of reference data to reference constants in a bunch of formulae on another sheet.

Is there any way to display the name of the range next to the range itself? For instance, if I have cell `AB23` named `SC_Item`, is there any way to make `AC23` display "SC_Item", perhaps with something along the lines of `=RANGENAME(AB23)` (completely made up, of course) or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a built in method (I haven't used 2013 yet) then this code will do the job.
It will check to see if the Target cell is within a named range and works for single cell named ranges or a cell that is part of a larger named range.

```
Public Function NamedRange(Target As Range) As String

    Dim vName As Variant

    For Each vName In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range(vName)) Is Nothing Then
            NamedRange = vName.Name
            Exit For
        End If
    Next vName

End Function
```

This will work if your named range is just a single cell (although I'm sure there's a better way).

```
Public Function NamedRange1(Target As Range) As String

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

        NamedRange1 = Target.Name.Name

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 1004 'Application-defined or object-defined error.
            NamedRange1 = Target.Address
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Module1.NamedRange1."
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Select

End Function
```